# Converting stringified array into actual array

Tags: php

The DB I am working with has an array of strings stored as a text value, such as:

> "[\"Radio\/CD\",\"TV\",\"Weight Gauge\"]"

(no idea why stored like this)

Anyway, I need to convert it into a regular array, such as:

> Array (
>       [0] => Weight Gauge
>       [1] => TV
>       [2] => Radio/CD )

Because of the way its stored I can't do a regular php explode, eg:

```
<?php
    $input  = '"[\"Radio\\\/CD\",\"TV\",\"Weight Gauge\"]"';
    echo "Input string:<br>" . $input . "<br><br>";
    $output = explode(",", stripslashes($input));
    print_r($output);
?>
```

The resulting array ( not how I want it ):

> Array ( [0] => "["Radio/CD" [1] => "TV" [2] => "Weight Gauge"]" )

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's double JSON encoded.

use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```php
$input  = '"[\"Radio\\\/CD\",\"TV\",\"Weight Gauge\"]"';
$output = json_decode(json_decode($input));
print_r($output);
```

this outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Radio/CD
    [1] => TV
    [2] => Weight Gauge
)
```

Comment: Thanks, lol, I had tried a single json_decode...hadn't thought about doing a double.